# Show a link in a menu even if user has no access

Tags: routes, users

I created a node/add/content-type menu link in my main menu, but it only shows to those who have access to it.

How could I show this to everyone, including anonymous users, and use http://drupal.org/project/r4032login for those who have no access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the menu a page with no access restrictions that contains the login form. (But still called "Add Content Type" or whatever it's currently called).

Using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), add redirects to node/add/content-type

- automatically redirects logged-in users
- automatically redirects anonymous once logged in from the above page

Answer (score 1):

Just found the [Menu item visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings for menu links. For example, if you want to create a 'My account' link that points to /user, both anonymous and registered users have access to the /user path, so both will see the link, even if anonymous users do not technically have an account. Using this module will allow you to only have your 'My account' link visible to registered users, and hide it from anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

Create menu link with the same name for only guests, which leads for login page

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem. It seems the only easiest way is to manually set the menu path as an absolute URL, ie. http://youdomain.com/***

Answer (score 0):

With the help from fishfree and the [menu token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) we can use a link like "[site:url-brief]/node/add/article" to solve the problem.