# Permission by role troubles my buttons

Tags: routes, users

I got a menu with sub-items members of the Role X. When a anonymous user visits the page, he can't see the menu. When the user logs in, he is able to see it.

How can I keep menus visible to everyone while keeping their permissions?

Comment: You didn't mention what you want to happen when a user can't access the links in the menu when they aren't logged in, but http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/show-menu-items-with-limit-access-to-anonymous-users is probably what you are looking for.